# Checking if a value is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

In my app, the registered user adds successfully comments on articles.

For example see this screenshot.

[image]

Now I want to read and display those comments in a recyclerview. Before that I want to check if the particular article has comments. If not then I should make a texview visible saying that there are no comments for that specific article. The news( which I get from Google News Api) don't have ids, so instead I using the newsTitle as shown in figure.

I wrote this code.

```
public class DisplayComments extends AppCompatActivity {

ArrayList<Comment> commentArrayList;
Toolbar mToolbar;
private DatabaseReference mDatabase;
private Intent i;
private String newsTitle;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_display_comments);

    mToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.display_comments_app_bar);

    setSupportActionBar(mToolbar);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setTitle("Display Comments");

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    commentArrayList = new ArrayList<>();

    i = getIntent();

    newsTitle = i.getStringExtra("newsTitle");

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    String userId = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();

    mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();

    Query query = mDatabase.child("comments").child("newsTitle").equalTo(newsTitle);

    query.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            if(dataSnapshot.exists()){
                Toast.makeText(DisplayComments.this,"There are comments posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }else{
                Toast.makeText(DisplayComments.this,"There are no comments posted",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });


  }
}
```

However, I always get There are no comments posted even for the articles with comments. How can make a good query that checks if the there are comments or not?

Thanks,

Theo.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need orderByChild('newsTitle') of the article in your query. Fix it like this:

```
Query query = mDatabase.child("comments").orderByChild("newsTitle").equalTo(newsTitle);
```

The above code will match the `newsTitle` filed with your given value.

Your code was trying to make a query but not defining the criteria.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.  Unfortunately, I don't have an id for the article. Check this link for example https://newsapi.org/v2/top-headlines?sources=abc-news&apiKey=98b995b151264acdb35e751ff6d22a3c

Comment: please see my answer now

Comment: Yes, that does it:). Thank you sir.